# Get number from one to x in a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get all the digits from `0` - `x` if x is a variable like so:

```
var x = 5
```

Then loop then so it logs them all individually by `console.log()`?

I was thinking I could use `.each()`, but it might make more sense to use something like `for` or while. I would post code, but I honestly can't think of a good/possible way to do this.

Comment: You really think you need jquery for this??

Comment: No, I was allowing the possibility for jQuery...

Comment: You might want to investigate some online or printed resources for learning JavaScript. Your question is about a truly elementary programming problem. (No offense meant of course; people aren't born knowing this stuff :-)

Comment: @PeeHaa - http://i.stack.imgur.com/sGhaO.gif

Comment: This question should be "how many identical for statements can i get in 5 minutes"

Comment: @Derek, Damn, feel like a nerd now for laughing out loud, waking the neighbours in the middle of night :D

Comment: None of these comments are helpful minus WaleedKhan's and Pointy's. This might be basic, but if I'm genuinely struggling with this, why should it be downvoted so many times? Nothing like turning away people who are new at something.

Comment: @Charlie I agree, there's nothing structurally wrong with your question. Downvotes should be about bad questions, not beginner questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really pretty basic:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < x; ++i) console.log(i);
```

(Use `<=` if you want to include the value of `x` in the output.)

Comment: Thanks for the downvote on this ridiculously simple question, mystery user.

Answer (score 3):

```
var x = 5;

for (var i = 0; i <= x; i++)
    console.log(i);
```

jQuery's `$.each()` method is for iterating over an object or array, so it doesn't make sense for this problem though you can do something silly like this:

```
$.each(new Array(x+1), function(i) {
    console.log(i);
});
```

I.e., create a new array with `x+1` elements, and then iterate over it specifically to use the index values. *I do not recommend this,* but since you asked about jQuery...

Answer (score 3):

Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/KKgPT/

```
x = 5;
for (i = 0;i <= x;i++) {
    console.log(i);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += i + ' ';
}​
```

Comment: Why would you need the var @Derek? My name is Derek too!

Comment: You'd use `var` to keep the variable in the current scope, otherwise `i` will be global even if that `for` loop appears inside a function. Sadly my name is not Derek.

Comment: Hi Derek - Because it would cause you many headaches if you put the loop in a function and put the function inside another loop.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that! Wow, I've sure done a lot of JavaScript and I've never ran into problems...wow. My mind is blown. I transitioned from C++ to JavaScript so I have just always assumed that scoping worked the same way. Wow.

Comment: Scoping is very different in JS because it has _only_ function and global scope, not block scope. (So, e.g., a variable defined inside a `for` loop is visible from anywhere in the containing function.)

Comment: Yeah, that's really strange. Well, I'm really glad I know that now!