# Combine same number array object with same number from other array?

Tags: javascript

I have an AJAX script which returns the results like this:

```
array one = ["<p>Number 1</p>","<p>Number 2</p>", "<p>Number 3</p>"]

array two = ["<p>Test</p>","<p>Other</p>", "<p>Random</p>"]
```

There are always the same number of objects in the first array as in the second.

Is it possible to combine the the first object from array one with the first object form array two, then the second object form array one, and the second object from array two, etc..?

Ex.)

```
["<p>Number 1</p>", "<p>Test</p>"]
["<p>Number 2</p>", "<p>Other</p>"]
```

Comment: @Sidharth Mudgal: uhm, I'm very curious about how it's possible to use jquery here?

Comment: @zerkms - http://i.stack.imgur.com/sGhaO.gif

Comment: @Sidharth Mudgal: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map And there is no `.map()` function in jQuery that can be applied for arbitrary array

Comment: @Derek Second time you've posted that on one of my questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360856/get-number-from-one-to-x-in-a-loop

Comment: @Charlie - That is not intended... Didn't know it was you.

Comment: @Derek: now we all think Sidharth Mudgal is a virtual account you use to propose jquery and post that image link afterwards

Comment: @Derek: I'm trying to joke. Failed in doing that :-S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = [];
for( var i = 0; i < one.length; i++){
    result[i] = [one[i], two[i]];
}
```

Comment: @Xanda - Because `result` is a common variable name? :D

Comment: @Xander: `result` for storing results? NO WAY!

Answer (score 1):

sure:

```
var results = [];

for(var i = 0; i < one.length; i++){
    results.push([one[i], two[i]]);
}
```